# Cannot make PyCharm comply with PEP8 indent on chained pandas expression

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

What should I use in the parameters to have PyCharm autofix not conflicting with PEP8 on that special case?

It is very annoying since I use autofix on save and then the linter during the CI fails.

[image: Pandas right indent]

[image: Pandas wrong indent]

This last example does not break with autofix but I find it less readable that the one I am targeting.
[image: Pandas other indentation]

Comment: Do you use some kind of linter ?

Comment: Please vote for the corresponding ticket in PyCharm's bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-27660